# Natbib/apalike.bst does not print booktitle for the inbook entry type

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I'm trying to cite a chapter from an IPCC report. It does not print the book title of the report thought. What am I doing wrong here? A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\cite{C.B.2014}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

While the bibtex entry is given by:

```
@inbook{C.B.2014,
author = {C.B. and Barros, VR and Mach, KJ and Mastrandrea, M.D. and van Aalst, M. and Adger, WN and Arent, DJ and Barnett, J and Betts, R and Bilir, Te and Birkmann, J and Carmin, J and Chadee, DD and Challinor, Aj and Chatterjee, M and Cramer, W and Davidson, DJ and Estrada, Yo and Gattuso, J-p and Hijioka, Y and Hoegh-Guldberg, O and Huang, HQ and Insarov, Ge and Jones, RN and Kovats, RS and Romero-Lankao, P and Larsen, JN and Losada, Ij and Marengo, Ja and McLean, RF and Mearns, Lo and Mechler, R and Morton, JF and Niang, I and Oki, T and Olwoch, JM},
booktitle = {Climate Change 2014: Impacts, Adaptation, and Vulnerability. Part A: Global and Sectoral Aspects. Contribution of Working Group II to the Fifth Assessment Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change},
doi = {10.1016/j.renene.2009.11.012},
isbn = {0960-1481},
issn = {09601481},
keywords = {adaptation,climate change impacts,vulnerability},
pages = {35--94},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
title = {{Technical summary}},
year = {2014},
}
```

The output does not have the booktitle in it. (The bibtex is created my Mendeley, I removed some lines that didn't influence this issue for simplicity).

C.B., Barros, V., Mach, K., Mastrandrea, M., van Aalst, M., Adger, W., Arent, D., Barnett, J., Betts, R., Bilir, T., Birkmann, J., Carmin, J.,Chadee,
D., Challinor, A., Chatterjee, M., Cramer, W., Davidson, D., Estrada, Y.,
Gattuso, J.-p., Hijioka, Y., Hoegh-Guldberg, O., Huang, H., Insarov, G.,
Jones, R., Kovats, R., Romero-Lankao, P., Larsen, J., Losada, I., Marengo,
J., McLean, R., Mearns, L., Mechler, R., Morton, J., Niang, I., Oki, T., and
Olwoch, J. (2014). Technical summary, pages 35–94. Cambridge University Press

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I took the liberty to edit the tags and title of your question in order to match the MWE you included.

Comment: The `apalike` bibliography style does by not include the `booktitle` field into citations of the `inbook` entry type. You might want to use the `incollection` type instead, that included the `title` and `booktitle` fields.

Comment: Given the nature of the enclosing work I think `@incollection` was the correct entry type from the start. At least in `biblatex` there is a distinction between `@book` (a work written in its entirety by the same set of authors) and `@collection` (a work with many chapters written by different people and compiled/edited by editors) that carries over to `@inbook` and `@incollection`. Since the different chapters in the IPCC report were written by different people, `@(in)collecton` seems to be the correct choice.

Comment: BTW: The `doi` looks wrong it links to something else entirely. You may want to fix that in your actual document.